# Preventing overlap of picture and table in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, overlap

How do I prevent overlap of picture and navbox in mediawiki? Our navbox template is a html table (source code http://www.wikiskripta.eu/index.php/%C5%A0ablona:Navbox?action=edit)?

I experience this overlap on my 1366x768 display.

I would post a picture, but I dont have the required 10 reputation.

Comment: Now you have enough reputation for a screenshot. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `<br clear="all"/>` between them.